# theoretical theory in Programming? How to

Tags: javascript, function, dom, theory

OK I have been watching so many tutorials from lynda.com and on youtube to learn programming in JavaScript but non of them teach how to use the programming logic?

I went through the syntax, object and classes, DOM, events, functions, At the end I did not know where to use them and why use such codes or functions for what reasons.

Maybe this is a dumb question.

Comment: You can visit http://www.stackoverflow.com and see the javascript issues and try to solve them. You can see that how other use these functions and how they work.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to learn programming is to find a problem and try to solve it, even if you have to make something up.  The traditional first problem to solve is how to display "Hello, World".  Give that a shot, and you'll quickly see why and where you'll need to use the tools you are learning about.